# regex with javascript - my 'injection' check needs to return true

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Basically, I have a code snippet that does not work and I am in a bit of a bind. I am new to Node.js, right now I'm working with express and a very simple MVC configuration. Everything runs fine, and if I hard set the return to false, the form input stops as it should. It's just this function - **regex.test**(first_name) - will still return false even if first_name is "<<<>>>". I tested the regex in Rubular, so I know it's right. What am I missing? I am pretty sure there is something with the npm/regex implementation that I am not used to (I come from Rails).

```
module.exports = {

validate_form_submission: function (first_name, last_name, street_address, city, state, zip) {

    var Regex = require("regex");
    var regex = new Regex(/([<>\/])/);
    var function_reply = true;

    //validate presence of fields
    if (!(first_name) || !(last_name) || !(street_address) || !(city) || !(state) || !(zip))
    {
        function_reply = false;
    };

    //check for SQL injection
    if ((regex.test(first_name)) || regex.test(last_name) || regex.test(street_address) || regex.test(city) || regex.test(state) || regex.test(zip))
    {
        function_reply = false;
    };

  return function_reply;
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have to `require("regex")`? A regex is a native value type in JavaScript and shouldn't require a node module to work. You can just write `var regex = /([<>\/])/;` I don't know if that will solve your issue or not, but requiring a node module shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: ok I will try that. Thanks! EDIT: that worked. Boo for the npm regex module. Thanks for the tip. If I switch out the two 'var (R/r)egex' calls for just 'var regex = /([<>\/])/;'

Comment: I made a small fiddle with with what I think you're testing against. I only used first_name in the example as a proof of concept. Is this the output you're expecting? https://jsfiddle.net/ecknd13r/

Comment: yes, thanks! Not sure why the npm module was getting in the way, but there it is. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! I've never used the npm module before, and it seemed unnecessary, so it threw a red flag. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

It was the npm regex module that just didn't need to be there.
The final code:

```
module.exports = {

    validate_form_submission: function (first_name, last_name, street_address, city, state, zip) {

        var regex = /([<>\/])/;
        var function_reply = true;

        //validate presence of fields
        if (!(first_name) || !(last_name) || !(street_address) || !(city) || !(state) || !(zip))
        {
            function_reply = false;
        };

        //check for SQL injection
        if ((regex.test(first_name)) || regex.test(last_name) || regex.test(street_address) || regex.test(city) || regex.test(state) || regex.test(zip))
        {
            function_reply = false;
        };

        return function_reply;
    }
}
```